# Error: "Variable Vector3"" is not a type name

Tags: c++, winapi, include

I have a class called `Vector3` in a header file called `Vector.h`. Everything is fine until I include this file in another header file. IntelliSense then marks every function that uses `Vector3` (as a parameter or return value) as an error: `Error: "Variable Vector3"" is not a type name`. I can't explain why this happens at all. I created a new test project and included `Vector.h` again, but in this new project everything compiles fine. Here's the code of the file:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_
#define VECTOR_H_

#include <math.h>

class Vector3
{
public:
    double x, y, z;

    Vector3();
    Vector3(double x, double y, double z);

    void normalize();
};

Vector3 normalize(Vector3 v);
Vector3 cross(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
Vector3 min(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
Vector3 max(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);

#endif
```

## Update:

I realised that there only is an Error if I include windows.h before Vector.h. If I dont include windows.h or if I include it after vector.h I dont get any error.

Comment: You're at least missing a copy constructor if yo use your `Vector3` class by value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The compiler generated one should work fine.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this header. Could you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @juanchopanza Is there a generated one, as soon you started to declare custom ones?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, there is,, unless you start providing move copy constructors/assignment operators. Then it becomes complicated.

Comment: Try using a different file name and change the #ifndef VECTOR_H_ to something else.  I bet it's already used by some other file you've included.

Comment: I realised that there only is an Error if I include `windows.h` before `Vector.h`. If I dont include `windows.h` or if I include it after `vector.h` I dont get any error.

Comment: I don't know if my suggestion worked for you.  But I'd like to point out that using very general names such as "vector" is bad idea.  Getting in the habit of naming your files and classes with more unique names will save you a lot of headache in the long run.